# Why oauth2_scheme is not working in fastapi authentication?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am creating a fastapi authentication system (register and login) and following documentation. I am using sqlalchemy, postgres and pydantic models.
My code is:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends, status
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from jose import jwt, JWTError
from passlib.context import CryptContext
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, Sequence, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

load_dotenv()

class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str
    
class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: str | None = None
    
class UserDB(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str | None = None
    full_name: str | None = None
    hashed_password: str
    disabled: bool | None = None
    
class UserResponse(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    email: str
    full_name: str
    disabled: bool

pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

oauth2_scheme=OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login")

SECRET_KEY=os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
ALGORITHM=os.getenv('ALGORITHM')
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES=int(os.getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES'))

DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('POSTGRES_URL')
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base=declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence("user_id_seq"), primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    email=Column(String(100), unique=True)
    full_name=Column(String(100))
    hashed_password = Column(String)
    disabled=Column(Boolean, default=False)

# Create the tables
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

# FastAPI app instance
app = FastAPI()

# Dependency to get the current database session
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()    
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

# Hashing passwords
def hash_password(password):
    return pwd_context.hash(password)

# Verify passwords
def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)

def get_user(username: str, db: Session=Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(User).filter(User.username==username).first()

def authenticate_user(username: str, password: str, db: Session=Depends(get_db)):
    user=get_user(username, db)

    if user and verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):

        
        return user
    else:

        
        return None
    
def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta | None = None):
    to_encode=data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire=datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
    else:
        expire=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt=jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt

async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
    credentials_exception=HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer'},
    )

    try:
        payload=jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str=payload.get('sub')
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data=TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user=get_user(username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user

async def get_current_active_user(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_user)]
):

    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user

# Register endpoint
@app.post("/register/")
def register(username: str, password: str, email: str, full_name: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    hashed_password = hash_password(password)
    print("------------------------\n\n\n\n")
    print("hashed_password: ", hashed_password)
    print("------------------------\n\n\n\n")

    existing_user=db.query(User).filter(User.username==username).first()
    if existing_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=409, detail="User already exists")

    new_user_data = {"username":username, "hashed_password":hashed_password, "full_name": full_name, "email": email, "disabled": False}
    user_create=UserDB(**new_user_data)
    new_user=User(**user_create.dict())
    db.add(new_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_user)
    return {"username": new_user.username}

# Login endpoint
@app.post("/login/")
def login_for_access_token(
    form_data: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()], db: Session= Depends(get_db)
):
    user = authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password, db)
    
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires=timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token=create_access_token(
        data={"sub":user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}

# demo function to define the way of getting info about a user securely
@app.get("/users_email", response_model=UserResponse)
async def read_users_email(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_active_user)]
):
    return current_user.email
```

The register and login endpoints are working fine. But when I  go to endpoint read_users_email, I get `401 Unauthorized` error.

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:33486 - "GET /users_email HTTP/1.1" 401 Unauthorized
```

The swagger screenshot is as below:
[Swagger Screenshot of read_users_email endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdM1j.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just got the solution. In swagger, I needed to click on Authorize button and there I needed to enter my username and password which populated the access_token to the login endpoint.